# cypress.should contains with regex with variable and substring

Tags: typescript, contains, cypress, should.js

How can I use regular expression with variable and substring in cypress.should to verify url by typescript? something like?

```
const string = /key_to_be_include\w+key1__`${v1}`,key2__`${v2}`/
```

```
//url: example.com/subdomain1/subdomainb/?key_xxxx=xxxxx&key_to_be_include=~alltextneed%25needtoBypass,key1__value1,key2__value2&...

const v1 = 'value1'
const v2 = 'value2'
const string = /key_to_be_include\w+key1__`${v1}`,key2__`${v2}`/
cy.url().should('contains', string);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `contains()` !

```
const string = /key_to_be_include\w+key1__`${v1}`,key2__`${v2}`/
cy.url().contains(string);
```

See [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2449)

Or try this or something like that :

```
const string = /key_to_be_include\w+key1__`${v1}`,key2__`${v2}`/
cy.url().should((url) => {
   expect(url).to.match(string)
}
```

See [here](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-an-element%E2%80%99s-text-contents)